# Using lxml, how can I append to a document and then wrap the entire document in a tag so I can search it with xpath?

Tags: python-2.7, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

Without the entire document being wrapped in a single tag, xpath gives me the "Extra content at end of the document" error. This is no issue, I could wrap the entire thing in one tag. But, in my program you will be writing to this document many times, and going into the document and then editing it defeats the purpose of having the program.

This is my code for writing to the document:

```
def write():
        ts = time.time()
        st = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        post = open('post.txt', 'w')
        document = etree.Element('document')
        title = raw_input('title>>')

        while 1:
            message = raw_input('post>>')
            post.write(message + '\n')
            if '[done]' in message:
                tags = raw_input('tags>>')
                break



        post = open('post.txt', 'r')
        postf = post.read()

        article = etree.SubElement(document, 'article', title=title, date=st, tags=tags)
        article.text = postf

        post.close()

        with open('postf.txt', 'a') as file:
            file.write(etree.tostring(article, pretty_print=True) + '\n')
            file.close()

        return document, article
```

And this is the code for searching the document:

```
if search in command:
    query = command.replace(search + ' ', "") #remove precursor
    post = open('postf.txt', 'r')
    postf = str(post.read())

    root = etree.fromstring(postf)

    articles = root.xpath('//article[contains(@tags, "%s")]' % query)

    for article in articles:
        print etree.tostring(article, pretty_print=True)
```

Is there a step in there somewhere I can add that will wrap the entire document in a single tag after each "write()" function is called?

Let me know if it is needed to post my full program, but I am fairly certain that this is the only part of the code that would effect what I am looking to do. If not, leave a comment and I will edit the rest in. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a "virtual wrapper" around your "multi-root" XML file by placing the following file in the same directory as that file:

```
<!DOCTYPE doc [
<!ENTITY e SYSTEM "article.xml">
]>
<doc>&e;</doc>
```

You can then target XPath expressions at this virtual document. That way you retain the ability to append data to the real article.xml, while being able to execute XPath queries at any time.